# How to assert paginations in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a category model with the following method:

```php
public static function index()
{
    return self::has('posts')->paginate(1);
}
```

My category controller:

```php
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::index();
    return view('categories.index', compact('categories'));
}
```

This is what I've tried, I am using RefreshDatabase trait.

```php
public function test_index_view_is_working()
{
    factory(Post::class, 5)->create();
    $response = $this->get(route('categories.index'));
    $response->assertViewHas('categories', Category::index());
}
```

This test fails for some reason:

```
Failed asserting that two objects are equal.

at tests/Feature/CategoryTest.php:38
    37|         $response->assertViewIs('categories.index');
  > 38|         $response->assertViewHas('categories', Category::index());

--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
                 'dispatchesEvents' => Array ()
                 'observables' => Array ()
                 'relations' => Array (
+                    'posts' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object (...)
                 )
                 'touches' => Array ()
                 'timestamps' => true
```

Comment: Does `$response->assertSee('Page 2');` would work?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier Can you clarify more? How would that help? I am trying to make sure the $categories are actually there

Comment: Based on your question *How to assert paginations in Laravel?* If you have `Page 2` on your page, it means your pagination works unless you have `Page 2` wrote somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because somehow the `posts` are eager loaded from the **view/controller** but not from the **tests**.

I'm guessing `return self::has('posts')->with('posts')->paginate(1);` could fix it.

Alternatively, you can test if you have the pagination at the bottom the page. Since `{{ $categories->links() }}` will add something like `Previous` and `Next` you can still look for it.

```
$response = $this->get(route('categories.index'));
$response->assertSee('Next');
```

Also, you can ensure that you paginate the categories but it won't ensure you have added the links at the bottom of the page.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\Paginator;
...

$response = $this->get(route('categories.index'));
$this->assertInstanceOf(Paginator::class, $response->viewData('categories'));
```

Comment: Just a note when using `$response->assertSee('Next');` The word 'Next' will not always exist

Comment: I don't have the exact word to look for. But the idea is to look for something, even in the HTML which is specific to the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running any migrations/factories in the `setUp` method of the test?

It looks like maybe there are no post records in your database so `$categories` is coming into the view as `null`.

Also side note if all you want to do is make sure that the view has the variable `$categories` you can use `$response->assertViewHas('categories');`. This is not ideal if you are wanting to make sure your view is getting actual data.

Comment: Laravel 7, PHPUnit 8.5.8

Comment: Can you post your entire test method? I am not sure why it would be expecting `null`.

Comment: Does your PostFactory create the relationship between itself and Category models? Based on what I can see it the test method is just creating 5 Post models but not associating them with a Category

Comment: Yes, it does attach them to a post.